# Trying to pass the value which was created dynamically, getting cypress reference error

Tags: javascript, jquery, automation, automated-tests, cypress

I'm trying to pass the value which is created dynamically first test case.
in first test case its creating the value, unable to refer the created value to another test case.

Here is my code, can anyone help me

```
describe('Create value in first test and pass it to next test',()=>{

    

    it('Create Variable',()=>{

        cy.visit('https://admin-demo.nopcommerce.com/login?ReturnUrl=%2Fadmin%2F');
        cy.get("[type='submit']").click();
        cy.xpath("(//p[contains(text(),'Customers')])[1]").click();
        cy.get('.menu-is-opening > .nav > :nth-child(1) > .nav-link > p').click();
        cy.xpath("//a[normalize-space()='Add new']").click();
        cy.get('#Email').type('autgomationedddex1121@gmail.com');
        cy.get('#Password').type('Admin110123')
        cy.get('#FirstName').type('tester1112')
        cy.get('#LastName').type('srinivas11')
        cy.get('#Gender_Male').click()
        cy.get('#DateOfBirth').type('3/4/1976')
        cy.get('#Company').type('Test Company')
        cy.get('#AdminComment').type('Automatin Tester')
        cy.xpath("//button[@name='save']//i[@class='far fa-save']").click().invoke('text').as('Variable')
        
        cy.get('@Variable').then((value) => {
            cy.log(`Dynamically created value: ${value}`);

          });
        
    })

    it('input for second test case',()=>{

        
        let value;
        cy.visit('https://demo.nopcommerce.com/')
        cy.xpath("//input[@id='small-searchterms']").type(value)
```

Getting Error  = cy.type() can only accept a string or number. You passed in:
`